Using Map in WSDTO request
`I have defined my WSDTO similar to below sample
 <bean class="xyz.dto.MyOrderWsDTO"> <property name="code" type="java.lang.String" /> <property name="additionalInformation" type="java.util.Map&lt;String,String>"/> </bean>
Now i m expecting MyOrderWsDTO as a request body in controller.
I am passing json as
{ "code": "abc", "additionalInformation": [ { "xyz": "hhj", "def": "value" } ] }
code is getting mapped but additionalInformation is coming as null.
I should be getting the values in additionalInformation as
xyz: hhj
def: value

java.util.Map is an interfece. Try different types such as List, HashMap, etc.
